# onclick to forward request to other URL

Tags: html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to open a page on click of a link. Below is the  link.

```
<a href='#' onClick=window.open('\\122.96.212.765\spread\form\5.0\tx1\NA\show\SPREAD_Show_ _33_PM\index_VIN_Test_ZASF91A.htm','_self') >CLICK HERE</a>.
```

But when i click the above link 404 error is displayed on the page as the URL is changing as below:

```
http://localhost:8080/122.96.212.765spreadform%05.SPREAD_Show_ _33_PMindex_VIN_Test_ZASF91A.htm
```

Please suggest, do i need to add ay extra code so that onclick even will work.

Comment: is this an IP 122.96.212.765?

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone , yes its an IP address, and if noticed it had removed few of the slashes from original URL and had been added % character before 5.0. Do i need to handle it in separate way in my java code.

Comment: IP address?and .765?is that even possible..thought it was upto 255......

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone - i just gave dummy IP address while posting :) , sorry about that.

Comment: y arent u giving in href directly?since in window.open u giving _self..might as well give in href itself the link

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone , because it should open in another window when i click from my application.

Comment: if thats the case replace _self with `_blank`

Comment: Also this will work `<a href="ur_ip" target="_blank">Click Me</a>`...Edit your link like this...remove `\\\``  before the IP and change the rest of the `\\` to `/`

Comment: After doing all the changes I have mentioned in my comments,edit your question,write **update** and post the new changes that I have told you,so that every1 can review it and help u further

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone - but i need to open that in another window when i click from my application, so that user can proceed with the current task and can view some data on the new window opened.

Comment: `<a href="ur_ip" target="_blank">Click Me</a>` target='_blank' does that..

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone - tried it as u mentioned above, but its appending http://localhost:8080/MyVINProject/122.96.212.765/spread/form/5.0/tx1/NA/show/SPREAD_Show_ _33_PM/index_VIN_Test_ZASF91A.htm .Do i need to handle anything at my code so that'http://localhost:8080/MyVINProject' is not added before actual URL.

Comment: instead of your ip try www.google.com n see wat happens

Answer (score 0):

can try changing your \'s to /'s

Comment: I disagree, and I neither critique'd or requested clarification. the other answers say the same thing, I just wasn't as verbose as them.

Answer (score 0):

As Geoff said, changing your backslash characters with forward slashes should solve your issue. I'm going to assume that because you tagged the question with [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) and [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) that you are trying to make this request to a Spring controller with a `@RequestMapping` matching the URL.

Your request is 404'ing because the actual request is being made to the incorrect URL because your backslash characters are causing issues with either parsing the URL, or generating the request URL. Because the request URL is malformed, it isn't getting picked up by your Spring Controller.

Fix your onclick URL and it should work.

Comment: i tried but issue is unable to fix, as its appending to http://localhost when i cilck the link and if noticed some of the slashes had been removed and % charater is added, how can i proceed writing java code to fix it or can i handle in database side from where i'm getting the URL - @James Massey .

Answer (score 0):

The url used in your code,

`"\\122.96.212.765\spread\form\5.0\tx1\NA\show\SPREAD_Show_ _33_PM\index_VIN_Test_ZASF91A.htm"`,

is syntactically incorrect.

The url does not have 'Scheme' part ("http:", "ftp:", etc.) and strange delimiter '\' are used instead of "/".

If valid url line "http://www.cnn.com/" is used, your code will work.
Try following:

```
<a href="#" onClick=window.open('http://www.cnn.com/','_self') >CLICK HERE</a>
```